# Need help to get the counts of Active and terminated employee

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the below scenario; please help!

I have two tables EMPLOYEE and TERMINATIONS with the below basic structure:

Employee table

```
Entry Date  EMP#   EMP Name    Hire Date   Rehire Date   Other Business Data

20140531    1      abc         05-MAY-08    05-MAY-08   
20140630    1      abc         05-MAY-08    05-MAY-08   
20140731    1      abc         05-MAY-08    05-MAY-08   
20140831    1      abc         05-MAY-08    05-MAY-08   
20140930    1      abc         05-MAY-08    05-MAY-08   
20150430    1      abc         05-MAY-08    13-APR-15   
20150531    1      abc         05-MAY-08    13-APR-15
```

Termination table

```
Entry Date  EMP #   EMP Name  Termination Date  Other Business Data

20141031    1       abc       31-OCT-14
```

I need to get the ACTIVE employee's count by using the below steps:
1. Take the MAX `entry date` date from employee table and check if the Re-Hire date from employee table is greater than the `termination date` in the termination table then add one for ACTIVE employees else that employee is terminated, so the termination count adds one!

Please help!

Comment: What have you tired?

Comment: I tried a LEFT OUTER JOIN with the EMPLOYEE table on REHIRE DATE greater than the TERMINATION DATE (which gives all rehires) with UNION of ALL Employees with Rehire lesser than hire date to get the employees who were hired. The problem is the data comes in every month and I need to get the MAX record compared to the termination table; which I am not able to figure out....

Comment: Can you show the query, the actual results from that query, and what you expected?